# Redirection issue on nextjs middleware

Tags: typescript, next.js, middleware, next-auth, nextjs-dynamic-routing

This is my middleware in next js when I try to redirect it showing Too many redirection  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Uegv.png) How to resolve this

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export function middleware(request) {

  console.log(request.nextUrl.pathname, "ppp")

  // return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(newPath, request.url));


  if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/training')) {

    const pathAfterTraining = request.nextUrl.pathname.substring('/training'.length + 1);

    const match = request.nextUrl.pathname.match(/^\/training\/([a-zA-Z]+)/);

    console.log("match",match,pathAfterTraining);
    console.log("match",request.nextUrl.pathname.split(("/")));

    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`/training/IN/contact-us`, request.url));
  }

}
export const config = {
  matcher:["/training/:path*","/","/training"]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to redirect to something else, like '/test/IN/contact-us' ? As I see it right now, my guess is that since the URL you redirect to matches the condition for your middleware to redirect, you will keep executing the middleware until it crashes.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Let say if user hit url like localhost:8000/training then I want to redirect to the new url i.e localhost:8000/training/IN or localhost:8000/training/US how can I do that. please help

Comment: I am not a NextJS pro, so I can't really give you a definitive answer. However, I can give you hints about what might be wrong and things you can test to try to understand the problem better. As I said in my previous comment, I think that redirecting /training/* to /training/IN will end up in an infinite loop (because /training/IN will be redirected to /training/IN again and again). That's why you could test quickly to redirect to an URL not containing /training. If you don't want to do that, then I guess, you could exclude /training/IN from the request condition (you can do a regex)